# PostgreSQL: subquery returns more than one row

Tags: postgresql

can anyone please help me?
I've already checked my SQL code several times and can not understand why an error occurs from time to time. In each subquery there is a hard limit to LIMIT 1, how can such a subquery return more than one line?

This issue can be reproduced by running this query in two parallel connections.

The column numeric_pool_id is the primary key and its value is unique (i was double-checked it).

```
            WITH update_current(number) AS (
                UPDATE numeric_pool
                SET updating_field = updating_field + 1,
                    date_modified = NOW()
                WHERE numeric_pool_id = (
                    SELECT numeric_pool_id
                    FROM numeric_pool
                    WHERE condition_field1 = 58
                    AND condition_field2 = 4
                    AND date_modified < NOW() - INTERVAL '150 s'
                    AND updating_field < 1
                    ORDER BY numeric_pool_id
                    LIMIT 1
                )
                RETURNING number
            ), insert_new(number) AS (
                WITH pool(number) AS (
                    VALUES (100), (200)
                )
                INSERT INTO numeric_pool (number, condition_field1, condition_field2, updating_field, date_modified)
                SELECT * FROM (
                    SELECT p.number, 58, 4, 1, NOW()
                    FROM pool p
                    LEFT JOIN numeric_pool dp ON (
                        p.number = dp.number
                        AND dp.condition_field1 = 58
                        AND dp.condition_field2 = 4
                    )
                    WHERE dp.numeric_pool_id IS NULL
                    LIMIT 1
                ) subquery
                WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM update_current)
                RETURNING number
            ), update_old(number) AS (
                UPDATE numeric_pool
                SET updating_field = 1,
                    date_modified = NOW()
                WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM update_current)
                AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM insert_new)
                AND numeric_pool_id = (
                    SELECT numeric_pool_id
                    FROM numeric_pool
                    WHERE condition_field1 = 58
                    AND condition_field2 = 4
                    AND date_modified < NOW() - INTERVAL '0 s'
                    ORDER BY date_modified
                    LIMIT 1
                )
                RETURNING number
            )
            SELECT COALESCE(
                (SELECT * FROM update_current),
                (SELECT * FROM insert_new),
                (SELECT * FROM update_old)
            ) AS number
```

I replaced the last part of the query by refusing to use COALESCE, then the error disappeared from the database logs. Therefore, one of the subqueries of COALESCE returned more than one line, likely the last subquery, because the first two subqueries should not return values on my data. However, this subquery is UPDATE on the primary key, this cannot return more than one row?

```
                SELECT number FROM (
                    SELECT * FROM update_current
                    UNION SELECT * FROM insert_new
                    UNION SELECT * FROM update_old
                ) finquery
                LIMIT 1
```

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE numeric_pool
(
  numeric_pool_id serial NOT NULL, -- Primary key
  condition_field1 integer NOT NULL,
  "number" bigint NOT NULL,
  condition_field2 integer NOT NULL,
  updating_field integer NOT NULL,
  date_modified timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT numeric_pool_pkey PRIMARY KEY (numeric_pool_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

This query in my application runs in parallel.

`PostgreSQL 9.6.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit`

Comment: Debug the query by running the individual parts and see which one returns more than one row.

Comment: It doesnt help. No one subquery returns more than one row. Looks like PostgreSQL bug.

Comment: Doesnt reproduce on PostgreSQL 10. It solved my problem. Thanks for watching =)